# Else if conditional does not apply in awk

Tags: awk, conditional-statements

`ping 8.8.8.8 -t 5 -c1 | awk '{if (/Time.*/) print $1,$2; else if (NR==1) print "from: " $3 " "}'`

When i use this line the else if doesn't work, it basically prints from and the ip no matter what first, even before the if conditional.
I want it print it only when the TTL is enough to reach the target (Or when there isn't a message involving Time to live exceeded)

This command is basically a traceroute written by me.

I don't know why the else if conditional doesn't work, i would love help.

The whole bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p 'IP: ' IP
read -p 'Max hops: ' hops

for hop_num in $(seq 1 $hops)
do
        if [[ $IP =~ [0-9] ]];then
                echo "$hop_num " | tr -d '\n'
                ping $IP -t $hop_num -c1 | awk '{if (/Time.*/) print $1,$2; else if (NR==1) print "Dest: " $3 " "}'
            
        else
                echo "not matched"
        fi
done
```

Ping output without awk filter:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.250.99.2 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Comment: What output do you exactly get? What output do you expect instead?

Comment: The output i get is:
from (8.8.8.8) 
From 10.250.99.2

I expect getting just 
From 10.250.99.2

Since it's the only part that matches the IF statement

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `ping`?

Comment: Added the ping output without awk.

Comment: As far as I understand, it doesn't help us to look at the whole bash script. You just need to post a) the input of `awk` (which happens to be the output of the `ping` command), b) the output you get with that input, and c) the output you want, obviously aside the `awk` command with its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. The first line doesn't match `Time.*` but NR is 1, as it's the first line. Therefore, $3 is printed, which happens to be `(8.8.8.8)`.

On the following lines, NR is never 1 again, so only the when the line matches `Time.*`, you'll get the output.

To fix the problem, remember the IP on the first line, and print it at the end if you didn't print anything.

```
awk '(NR==1){f=$3}(/Time/){print$1,$2;p=1}END{if(!p)print f}'
```

`f` is used to remember the IP from the first line, `p` is the flag that tells us whether we printed anything.

Comment: Oh, this makes sense.
Didn't know awk runs each line separately.

Is there a way to print it correctly like wanted?

Comment: @PierreFrançois Posted the wanted  output in a comment under my question, same with the ping output etc..

What choroba posted in the update works tho, ty for your help!

Comment: I just understood what you wanted. You shoud have posted two inputs with their corresponding outputs, and we should have understood the behaviour you wanted with the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -t 5 -c1 | awk '/Time/{print $1,$2}(NR==1){print "from: " $3 " "}
```

Comment: Same output as the one with if and else if.

Comment: @benshalev: the problem is that we hardly guess the output you really want. See my comment under your question. We will help you better if you clarify this, posting the exact output you want for a given input.